# Is detected iPhone 6 and 6+ height 568 points?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am maintaining an app that was developed before the release of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. The developers of the app placed elements on screen using code. They detected screen heights placed views depending on the points of the screen height. As a maintainer of the app I need to make sure the app works well on the latest versions of the iPhone. The app seems to be working well on iPhone 6 and 6+ without modification and the screen height returned is 568. Will the app behave well on actual devices or is it simulator errors?

Answer (score 0):

You might not get the app through the App Store. The problem is that the app is *not* actually "working well"; the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus are regarding it as an iPhone 5 app and are displaying it in "zoomed" mode. Apple might not accept that in a newly submitted build. If you give the project a Launch Screen, it will become a "native" iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus app, and then you will see what the story really is.

Comment: I have designed a new launch screen for the app using iPhone 6 and 6+ resolutions. What I can do is replace iPhone 5's graphics with iPhone 6+'s resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Matt is right. I wrote a little method in my Utilities class that to determine screen sizes. The comments tell you what should be returned in the log for each device. The screen size and reported size are the same for all but iPhone 6 Plus.

```
+ (NSInteger)deviceType {
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat deviceScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    LFDeviceType device = LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        device = LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        // Classic has a resolution of 480 × 320
        if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 1.0f ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic;
        // Retina has a resolution of 960 × 640
        } else if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 2.0f ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina3_5;
        // Retina 4" has a resolution of 1136 x 640
        } else if (screenSize.height == 568 || screenSize.width == 568 ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina4;
        // iPhone 6 has a resolution of 1334 by 750
        } else if (screenSize.height == 667 || screenSize.width == 667 ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhone6;
        // iPhone 6 Plus has an actual size of 2208 × 1242 and resolution of 1920 by 1080
        // Reported size is 736 x 414 @3x
        } else if (screenSize.height == 736 || screenSize.width == 736 ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhone6Plus;
        }

    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        device = LFDeviceTypePadClassic; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        if(deviceScale == 1.0f) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePadClassic;
        } else if (deviceScale == 2.0f) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePadRetina;
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"The device is %@ scale is %f and the height is %f and width is %f", device, deviceScale, screenSize.height, screenSize.width);

    return device;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

currently your app is working in zoomed mode, if you add splash screen for 6 and 6+ then your app will be in actual size, after include splash screen for 6 and 6+ you will get actual screen size.

Comment: Sorry, but you're just plagiarizing my answer and no more.

Comment: @matt sry brow didn't checked your answer